# Can we delete Android system WebView app to free up space?

Tags: system, webview

I am looking to free up some space on my android device.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot delete it without root as it is a system app.
2. even if you could delete it, it wouldn't free up space for other apps. System apps reside in their own space (`/system`), which during normal operations is mounted read-only.
3. even ignoring the other two points: deleting Webview would cause several apps to just stop working as they depend on it for displaying content (even local one).

TL;DR: No, don't.

Comment: Regarding bullet #2, deleting a system app actually frees *a bit* of space in `/data`, because the system doesn't build a Dalvik/ART cache for it anymore. Disabling it doesn't help, though.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman just "uninstalling" it for user0 (if there isn't another user) doesn't achieve that? I've never checked. And if you go for that: disabling *and deleting its data* helps a bit, too :)

Comment: @Izzy You have a point: since `/data` holds both a system app's... data and its updates, deleting everything either before or after disabling it can save up some usable space. Of course, if one is open to rooting, they can trick their phone into thinking a system app has been removed, and still reap the "no Dalvik" benefit. The `Debloater` module comes to mind - *I'm not affiliated, but I do use it*.